# Statistics regarding different data sets having a common response variable

Tags: feature-selection

Lets assume one has 2 datasets: with different number of rows (samples) and columns (features). Each of these 2 datasets have a column as a binary response variable. Lets say healthy or not.
What sort of statistical methods can be used to help us for better feature selection results, or better performance in classification models, utilizing both datasets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them together, call them a single dataset, add a column indicating which dataset they came from if that represents something meaningful you can measure out of sample (location?), proceed as normal with multiple imputation or another technique to deal with all the missing data this generates.

Comment: How to put together 2 datasets which differ in their attributes (columns)? E.g. the columns of the first dataset are x1,x2,..,x10 and the columns of the second are y1,y2,..,y20  where Xi and Yi are not the same variables. This resembles multi-modal data but the subjects (rows) are not the same. The only common column is the response variable. Regularized Canonical Correlation Analysis is the only statistics that seems to me a bit close to this problem.   Do you mean a block diagonal structure where zeros complement the non-existent data? In this case what kind of statistics would be useful?

Comment: all the rows of x1-x10 will be null in the second data set. All the rows of y1-y10 will be null in the second data set. http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~jls/mifaq.html